# Using HyperLedger Fabric certificates for signing a message

Tags: certificate, hyperledger-fabric

We have generated public and private keys in Hyperledger Fabric using its API which are getting stored in crypto_material folder.

Now, on one machine we want to sign a message using private key and verify its validity on second machine using corresponding public key. To achieve this task we have written code as follows.

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var secp256k1 = require("secp256k1");
var fs = require("fs");
var sha256 = require('sha256')

let pub_key_file = "./keyfiles/4d4a0d669d507ff05c73c9e1ca40fb5f909f9806df138a82767a739e9de31240-pub"
fs.access(pub_key_file, fs.F_OK, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("readfile error : ", err);
    return;
  }
})

var public_key = fs.readFileSync(pub_key_file);

// Reading private key from file system.
let priv_key_file = "./keyfiles/4d4a0d669d507ff05c73c9e1ca40fb5f909f9806df138a82767a739e9de31240-priv"
fs.access(priv_key_file, fs.F_OK, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("readfile error : ", err);
    return;
  }
})

var private_key = fs.readFileSync(priv_key_file);

var privKey = new Uint8Array(sha256(private_Key).match(/.{1,2}/g).map(byte => parseInt(byte, 16)));
var pubKey = new Uint8Array(sha256(public_Key).match(/.{1,2}/g).map(byte => parseInt(byte, 16)));

console.log(pubKey instanceof Uint8Array)  //returning true here
console.log("value : ", secp256k1.privateKeyVerify(privKey)); //returning true here
console.log("value : ", secp256k1.publicKeyVerify(pubKey)); // Getting error like expected public key to be an Uint8Array with length [33, 65] hyperledger fabric
```

Why the secp256k1 module is successfully verifying privateKey but failing with publicKey.

Comment: What are you using to generate the key pair?

Comment: Using caClient.register(enrollmentID:username, affiliation:userOrg.toLowercase(), Type:user, attrs:[{name:"role", value:attr, ecert:true}]}, adminUserObj); method invocation public and private keys were generated and stored in crypto_material folder.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you performed an ***enroll*** after you registered the identity using ***register***.

You will actually have multiple issues with what you are attempting to do.

1. Fabric CA generates EC keys using NIST-approved curves (e.g. secp256r1,secp384r1) and not secp256k1 used by Bitcoin
2. Fabric CA produces a private key and an X509 certificate from the corresponding public key
3. The private key and X509 certificate are returned as PEM-encoded blobs as well.

There are many libraries out there which you can use to sign/verify using PEM encoded private keys and X509 certificates.  [jsrsasign](https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/) is fairly straightforward.

You can also use some of the modules provided by the Fabric Node SDK as well depending on what you are doing.

Comment: OK Gari Singh, I will try above suggestions. We have setup Blockchain network using HLF and I want a machine outside of HLF N/W to send a message encrypted using HLF private key to HLF N/W. To achieve this we are trying to encrypt message generated in a machine outside of HLF N/W using HLF Private key and send the same to HLF N/W where it can be verified for its authenticity and integrity using HLF Public key.  The message will be sent to HLF N/W through an intermediate gateway application which acts as HLF Client.

Comment: Do you want to encrypt or sign?

Comment: encrypt and decrypt in two different PCs and I am looking for Node.js based modules